# facing issue regarding MYSQL RAM fill up due to this my site is down

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am facing this issue. I optimised all my queries. But still all in vain.
My Application is built in Codeigniter. I want to clear mysql RAM. Is there any way to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

Alternatively you can use this:

```
FLUSH QUERY CACHE;
```

See the [Query Cache Status and Maintenance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html) documentation page for more information.